# Different plot results in Matlab and R - Update question

Tags: r, matlab

I have the code below in Matlab that display and extract the x,y boundaries to a csv.

Matlab code:

```
url='https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/car-icon-auto-vehicle-isolated-transport-icons-automobile-silhouette-vector-id1273534607?k=20&m=1273534607&s=170667a&w=0&h=BVJi9caoO31fkEY0p8Q9KYXiWROSRo7LbtgnBXfujWM=';
I = imread(url);
 
imshow(I);
axis('on','image') ;
hold on;
BW = imbinarize(I);
BW = imcomplement(BW);
BW = imfill(BW,'holes');
imshow(BW);
[B,L] = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');

k=1;
stat = regionprops(I,'Centroid');
b = B{k};
c = stat(k).Centroid;
y = b(:,1);
x = b(:,2);

plot(x,y, 'g', 'linewidth', 2);
T=table(x,y) 
writetable(T,'E:/t.csv')
```

[image]

When I plot the CSV in R using this code:

```
csv_data<-read.csv("E:/t.csv")
plot(x = csv_data$x,
     y = csv_data$y,
     xlab = "X",
     ylab = "Y")
```

I get this:
[image]

This is mainly due to the different axis definitions between the languages. Therefore, how can I rotate/flip the table generated in Matlab so the R/excel/JMP/etc graph will look the same?

Comment: Looks like you swapped the position of x and y in the plot command of the two codes.

Comment: Thanks I fixed this error but still it is not the same

Comment: R picks the axes limits to make the data fit "nicely" in. You can control the axes limits in base R with plot(..., xlim=c(0,500)) and respectively ylim=c(lower, upper) to your liking. In base R you can "reverse" the axis by flipping the upper and lower limit. This is one way of inverting your figure, i.e. ylim = c(350, 0). Please note that this inversion does not change the value (here y-value). You could then "overwrite" the labels of the tick marks. But I suggest to manipulate your data and work with the native (calculated values), e.g. y2 =( (-1) * y ) + 350. This will make y2 positiv.

Comment: @ray thanks but I updated the question so the solution will be in Matlab to match other statistical and  spreadsheet applications.

Comment: @Iroca In MATLAB, you can get the 2nd image just by flipping `x` and `y`.

Comment: @lmran, thanks. Can you please be more specific. What function do you recommand?

Comment: @Iroca You can use the `flipud` function. I don't know why SO didn't notify me. I just saw your reply.

Comment: For example, `xf = flipud(x)` and `yf=flipud(y)`.

Comment: @lmran, Thanks but I still get the same graph not flipped/mirrored

Comment: I got [this](https://imgur.com/kSfsjJQ) in MATLAB using the `flipud` function as mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

`T=table(x,(-1*y))` will solve this issue

Comment: Have you checked it?